# Appending a div to a div created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am iterating an array and creating a div on the fly as follows:

```
   $.each(item,function(k,item2) {
     html = '<td><div id="test">'+item2.Name +'</div></td>'

     //For just testing purpose , I am adding a div dynamically as:
     $("#test").append("<div class='test class'></div>");
   });
```

But finally when I browse the html page , the new div with class='test class' is not to be found at all.
Is there anything which I am missing?

Edit : 
In the html tag "html", there are multiple divs , and I want to append to a particular div by id

Not exactly sure what the problem is :
but after the html has been created ,
`$("#test").append("<div class='test class'></div>");` works but appending using $(html).find() doesnt

Comment: Can you do `console.log($("#test"))` and `console.log(item)`?

Comment: `$(html).find('#test').append("<div class='test class'></div>");`

Comment: Also might just be that the div is collapsed? Try `$('.test.class')` in console after you run the function

Answer (score 2):

> As element is not appended in the DOM, you can not access it using `$` selector.
>   You can use `html` variable holding element in the form of `string`, content will not be the `document` but you can access `#test` element after wrapping it with `$`

```js
 $.each(item, function(k, item2) {
   var html = '<td><div id="test">' + item2.Name + '</div></td>';
   $(html).find('#test').append("<div class='test class'></div>");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the element with id "test" dynamically, you have just assigned in variable. please try the below code

```
$.each(item,function(k,item2) {
     html = '<td><div id="test">'+item2.Name +'</div></td>';
     $('any existing element class/id').html(html);
     //For just testing purpose , I am adding a div dynamically as:
     $("#test").append("<div class='test class'></div>");
});
```